# Were the zoo apes intelligent in "Rise of the Planet of the Apes"?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2011, rise-of-the-planet-of-the-apes

Near the end of the movie, when the zoo apes were freed, they seemed to have joined the revolt to escape to freedom. **Were they somehow intelligent by any means?** They all left in unison and their behavior didn't seem like that of normal zoo ape that's been kept in captivity. Were they infected by the drug at all?

Also, were these apes the ones that trailed behind on the Golden Gate Bridge?

Below Caesar rolls the canisters to infect the apes in their cages and make them 'intelligent'.

[image: Caesar rolling the canisters releasing the gas for apes in the cages]

Later the 'intelligent' apes free the apes in the zoo, which then follow them into the city and across the Golden Gate bridge.

[image: Later the intelligent apes freeing the zoo apes]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prior to freeing the apes in the primate shelter from the cages, Caesar gave them the more powerful version of the drug that made him smarter.  Note this drug is in fact a virus.  This version of the drug was more virulent and was highly contagious.  Later on, when Caesar freed the zoo animals, he and the other apes presumably were still contagious, spreading the drug as they interacted with humans and apes alike.

Also yes, they were mostly the same apes that were fighting on the Golden Gate Bridge.  The rest were the apes from the Primate Shelter.

Comment: I mean the apes that were in the actual zoo, outdoors. Not the apes in their cages where Caesar was also being held.

Comment: @sunpech There you go, I've updated it to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Having just watched it, I think the zoo apes were not intelligent, but were in fact following normal ape pack behavior. During the end scenes there seems to be smart apes commanding and regular apes soldiering. However, do to the fact that the effects spread to the children, within one or two generations they would all be in the style that we see in the other PotA movies.

Answer (score 0):

In the scene where Caesar finds the canisters in his father's refrigerator, there are three canisters that he takes. When he gases the apes in the rehabilitation center, he only uses two. If the apes at the zoo are all kept in the same area at night then he could have gone there and used a single canister on that group.

This would also explain how Caesar and the other rehabilitation apes knew where the zoo was at. Thus all the apes at the rehabilitation center, the zoo, and Genesys Labs, would have been intelligent.

Answer (score -1):

I honestly think this is an oversight from the writers. Everyone is saying that they got smart via contagion, but this makes no sense time-wise. In the scene where the zoo apes are freed by the gorilla, we see apes picking up pieces of the fence to use as spears, immediately after being freed. This does not seem like normal chimp behavior, but rather something an intelligent chimp would do. I don't believe the gorilla could infect the other apes with the virus in less than a few seconds, we saw that the virus would take at least a few hours to have its effect when Caesar spreads it to the apes in the shelter. Either something happened off screen which was poorly communicated, or the writers just didn't think about it.

Comment: [Using spears is well within the cognitive range of chimpanzees](https://www.animalcognition.org/2015/11/01/spear-hunting-chimps/).